# How to use ajaxmanager with jquery ajax request?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to use the ajax blockmanager plugin to manage my jquery ajax requests, but I'm not sure how to implement it...

```
 // Follow button click event
    $('#loginBtn').click(function () {
        var that = this;

        var request = {
            'username': $('#txtUsername').val(),
            'password': $('#txtPassword').val()
        };

        var params = $.toJSON(request);

        ajaxManager.add($.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/Login.aspx/Login",
            data: params,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.d === true) {
                    window.location = "dashboard.aspx";
                }
                else {
                    $('#errorMessage').slideDown();
                }
            }
        }));
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a bit outdated question... But if anyone comes across this issue:

You are passing the already created/started request as a parameter to the manager.
You should only pass its options. The request will be created and handled by the manager.

```
    ajaxManager.add({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/Login.aspx/Login",
        data: params,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.d === true) {
                window.location = "dashboard.aspx";
            }
            else {
                $('#errorMessage').slideDown();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ajaxManager instantiated?

```
//create an ajaxmanager named cacheQueue
var ajaxManager = $.manageAjax.create('cacheQueue', {
    queue: true, 
    cacheResponse: true
});
```

Comment: yes, I just don't understand how to hook it up to the jquery ajax request

Comment: what do you mean hook it up? Are you ajax request not firing?

Comment: Am I doing it right by wrapping the $,ajax request in the add method?

Comment: It fires a Post and Get request... and it isn't blocking

Comment: Ya, that's where I downloaded it from.

Comment: Url and Documentation don't exist anymore (to that website/link) :(

Answer (score 0):

You first create the manager

```
this.ajaxManager = $.manageAjax.create("aiapi", {
        queue: true,
        cacheResponse: true,
        maxRequests: 3,
        abort: this.abortCallback
    });
```

where the queue of calls is active, max concurrent requests are 3, and the caching is enabled. The common `abortCallback` is like

```
this.abortCallback = function (response) {
        Logger.log("APIManager.abortCallback " + Utils.toString(response));
    };
```

It's convenient to add the common `ajaxSetup` setup like

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        cache: true,
        timeout: 10 * 1000
    });
```

Here you can see the response timeout in `msec` set to 10 sec.
You then do a `GET` like

```
    this.DoGet = function (url, method, timeout) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var options = {
                type: 'GET',
                url: url + method,
                contentType: "application/json",
                timeout: (15 * 1000) // sets timeout to 60 seconds
            };
            if (timeout) options.timeout = timeout;
            const errorCallback = function (error) {
                console.error(error);
                return reject(error);
            };
            const successCallback = function (data) {
                return resolve(data);
            };
            const completeCallback = function (data) {
                return resolve(data);
            };
            options.error = errorCallback;
            options.success = successCallback;
            //options.complete= completeCallback;
            $.manageAjax.add("default-queue", options);

            /*$.ajax(options)
                .done(function (data) {
                    return resolve(data);
                })
                .fail(function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    return reject(error);
                })
                .always(function () {
                    // called after done or fail
                });*/
        });
```

You can see in the comment the version without the ajax manager. And it the same way to `POST` is like

```
this.DoPost = function (url, method, body, timeout) {
        try {
            body = JSON.stringify(body);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(body);
            return reject(error);
        }
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var options = {
                type: 'POST',
                url: url + method,
                data: body,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout: (15 * 1000) // sets timeout to 60 seconds
            };
            if (timeout) options.timeout = timeout;

            const errorCallback = function (error) {
                console.error(error);
                return reject(error);
            };
            const successCallback = function (data) {
                return resolve(data);
            };
            options.error = errorCallback;
            options.success = successCallback;
            $.manageAjax.add("default-queue", options);

            /*$.ajax(options)
                .done(function (data) {
                    return resolve(data);
                })
                .fail(function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    return reject(error);
                })
                .always(function () {
                    // called after done or fail
                });*/
        });
    }//DoPost
```

The important thing here is the name of the ajax queue when adding a new `GET / POST` request via the api

```
$.manageAjax.add("default-queue", options);
```

This means basically that you can have one or more queues, that improves your requests parallelism.